# When I edit line 14 addReminder function the app break any insight to what I am doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, types, react-redux, jsx

In this code below, I keep running into this error message "Error: Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. Have you misspelled a constant?" This I received the error message after editing my addReminder on line 14. Any insight?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { addReminder } from '../action';

class App extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        text: ''
    }
}

addReminder() {
    this.props.addReminder(this.state.text);
}

    render(){
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <div className="title">
                    Reminder Pro
                </div>
                <div className="form">
                    <div className="form=group">
                        <input
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="I have to..."
                        onChange={event => this.setState({text: event.target.value})}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <button 
                    type="button"
                    className="btn btn-success"
                    onClick={() => this.addReminder()}
                    >
                        Add Reminder
                    </button>
                 </div>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({addReminder}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Comment: Well the error itself explains what's gone wrong. Apart from that, you need to show us the *problematic* code. Showing us working code that breaks when you "edit" it in some non-specific way isn't really useful

Comment: The issue will be in your `addReminder` action creator.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the insight. I found where the issue was occurring. Thank again.